# Tag requested for ODL Studio questions?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, tags, etiquette

We've created an open source (LGPL) application called ODL Studio for territory design, vehicle routing, and viewing maps (i.e. of customer points) based on Excel data. We're considering the merits of using GIS SE as a Q&A site for people needing help using this software. We've hit a stumbling block though - we'd need a tag odl-studio to be available (so we can get notifications) and we'd have to answer a lot of questions to get our own reputation level to the level where we can do this ourselves. I know traditionally tags are created when there's a sufficient number of posts on a subject but its a chicken-and-egg situation. We can't start directing users to GIS SE (via links on our webpage, youtube videos etc) until that tag is present, as most of the time we'd probably need to be the people answering the questions and hence we need the tagging / notifications. However until we start directing users to GIS SE, no-one's going to post ODL Studio queries on there.

I'd guesstimate one or two queries a week would be posted on GIS SE. As a lot of queries are similar, my hope is to build a body of user knowledge on GIS SE that future users can reference rather than create a new query.

So, is it a good idea to use GIS SE for this purpose and if so, can someone with the necessary reputation please create the tag odl-studio ?

There's some more information on ODL Studio here:

- Youtube videos https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0DJdubVWX_A and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cyIcVwHf524 . You can see a few people posting queries on the video comments as there's no user forum right now.
- http://www.opendoorlogistics.com/software/odl-studio/

Also see this discussion [Allowing GIS SE to be support for particular software products?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3180/allowing-gis-se-to-be-support-for-particular-software-products) on allowing GIS SE to be used for software products support. We would follow the practices listed under 'An Open Letter to GIS Project Teams'. So when we direct users to GIS SE, we would include strongly worded advice on using GIS SE best practice / conventions etc (e.g. single question / single post, accepting answers, formulating questions properly). We'd also make it clear that feature requests, bugs and similar should NOT be posted on GIS SE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's go by parts:

> We're considering the merits of using GIS SE as a forum for people needing help using this software.

Ok, but be aware all questions asked here will be under the Stack Exchange (and GIS SE) rules, so it might happen not all types of questions you are expecting  will fit here.

PolyGeo already mentioned in [comments](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4512/gis-se-for-odl-studio-users-need-tag#comment8127_4512) this is not like a forum. So, I'd advise you reading at least the [help center](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help) page to get more acquainted about how this site works.

Also, **very important**, if people that will be responding here have affiliation with product/company 'x', and such answers will **recommend** the software among other possible solutions, it must be clearly emphasized in the answer; otherwise answers can be considered spam. This guideline is part of our [FAQ](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).

For example, adding a disclosure of the following type at the bottom of answers:

> Disclosure: I work for company 'y'.

In such cases, make sure to answer objectively, without making propaganda of it. And of course, don't just answer like 'software x can do this/use software x', but show the 'how to' process.

On the other hand, when a question is specific about software 'x', no affiliation is needed. All that it is necessary is to answer the question satisfactorily.

> We've hit a stumbling block though - we'd need a tag odl-studio to be available (so we can get notifications).

Devdatta Tengshe already created the [odl-studio](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/odl-studio). You can now suggest a [tag-excerpt and a tag-wiki](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/03/24/redesigned-tags-page/) to it. Make sure to try following the guidelines for excerpt and wikis (they are in the hyperlink).

> Also see this discussion "Allowing GIS SE to be support for particular software products?" on allowing GIS SE to be used for software products support. We would follow the practices listed under 'An Open Letter to GIS Project Teams'. So when we direct users to GIS SE, we would include strongly worded advice on using GIS SE best practice / conventions etc (e.g. single question / single post, accepting answers, formulating questions properly). We'd also make it clear that feature requests, bugs and similar should NOT be posted on GIS SE.

That is it.